# Auth0 authentication with Cypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, auth0

I am trying to create a login command for Cypress and noticed their blog on how to do this does not match the expected values for the [Auth0 React SDK](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-react). It appears they have used a custom express app to handle the login vs using the SDK to handle this (as per the [offical Auth0 documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-react)).

The Cypress [official documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/auth0-authentication#Custom-Command-for-Auth0-Authentication) produces a local storage key value pair that looks like the below.

```js
const item = {
        body: {
          decodedToken: {
            claims,
            user: { ... },
            audience,
            client_id,
          },
        },
        expiresAt: exp,
      }

window.localStorage.setItem('auth0Cypress', JSON.stringify(item))
```

However the one created by the Auth0 React SDK produces something similar to:

```js
const item = {
      body: {
        access_token,
        audience,
        client_id,
        decodedToken: {
          claims,
          user: { ... },
          encoded,
          header
        },
        expires_in,
        id_token,
        scope,
        token_type
      },
      expiresAt: exp
    }

window.localStorage.setItem(`@@auth0spajs@@::${client_id}::${audience}::${scope}`, JSON.stringify(item))
```

I am able to get the `https://${auth)_domain}/oauth/token` request working, however am not able to work out how to get the data from the response in a way for it to fit the data structure the Auth0 react SDK wants it in.

Has anyone had any success with this?

---

After doing some exploring, it appears the response I get back from the `/oauth/token` does not contain all of the fields that the value the Auth0 React SDK outputs when it signs in.

I have also noticed that [Auth0 has a guide](https://auth0.com/blog/cypress-write-automated-tests-to-validate-web-applications/#The-Test-Pyramid-and-Importance-of-E2E-tests) on how to integrate with Cypress however it does not use this SDK, instead it uses the SPA SDK. That guide also uses a custom login form, where I am using the LockUI.

One thing to note is that I am not using an backend to authenticate (like in most of the examples). I using the `loginWithRedirect` to login as per the offical recommendation.

Comment: Check this article https://auth0.com/blog/end-to-end-testing-with-cypress-and-auth0/

Comment: The SKD used in this guide is not the same as the recommended SDK for React. It makes use of APIs such as `checkSession()` which are not exposed in the official React SDK.

Comment: Don't worry about checkSession. You don't have to call it explicitly. Auth0 React SDK is simply a wrapper fro atuh0 spa sdk so it calls checkSession implicitly all the time (e.g. when you create a client). When you do redirect to callback with a token, if you set up everything properly in Auth0 React SDK, your sdk will set all required cookies and storage properties.

Comment: You can also go through the whole Lock workflow with lockUI see example here https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/blob/ac8d8bb70e8ba51cb3a7d4b8e3fa8a6261b5a1ee/cypress/support/commands.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of investigating and help from the Auth0 team, I was successful in making this work.

Here is the code I used:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("login", () => {
  cy.clearLocalStorage();

  const email = "";
  const password = "";
  const client_id = "";
  const client_secret = "";
  const audience = "";
  const scope = "";

  cy.request({
    method: "POST",
    url: "",
    body: {
      grant_type: "password",
      username: email,
      password,
      audience,
      scope,
      client_id,
      client_secret,
    },
  }).then(({ body: { access_token, expires_in, id_token, token_type } }) => {
    cy.window().then((win) => {
      win.localStorage.setItem(
        `@@auth0spajs@@::${client_id}::${audience}::${scope}`,
        JSON.stringify({
          body: {
            client_id,
            access_token,
            id_token,
            scope,
            expires_in,
            token_type,
            decodedToken: {
              user: JSON.parse(
                Buffer.from(id_token.split(".")[1], "base64").toString("ascii")
              ),
            },
            audience,
          },
          expiresAt: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + expires_in,
        })
      );
      cy.reload();
    });
  });
});
```

You have to make sure that the config you pass in is **exactly** the same as the config you use in the Auth0 Provider.

Once thing to note that tripped me up, was that I was also using refresh tokens. If this is the case make sure to add `offline_access` to your scope.

I have a public repo to download a working solution - https://github.com/charklewis/auth0-cypress.

Comment: Does this still work with you in 11/2021. I tried this code and it did not work for me. I am sure it something I missed. Any advice?

Comment: According to this link https://community.auth0.com/t/oauth-token-not-returning-id-token/8303 you need to add openid access in the scope order to get the id_token.  Otherwise there will be an error in the decodedToken.

Comment: In general, if it doesn't work then you need to play with the scope parameter to ensure it is set correctly.

Comment: I am success with this implementation in browser mode, however in headless mode it does not work and stays in login page. Does it happen to you?

Answer (score 1):

For those who come across this in the future. We created an alternative approach of testing Auth0 with Cypress which doesn't require changing code in the actual application.

The approach that we use is to run a local service that exposes the same API as Auth0. We packages this service as an NPM package. You can read about it in our blog post https://frontside.com/blog/2022-01-13-auth0-simulator/

Here is what your test end up looking like,

```js
import auth0Config from '../../cypress.env.json';

describe('log in', () => {
  it('should get token without signing in', () => {
    cy.createSimulation(auth0Config)
      .visit('/')
      .contains('Log out')
      .should('not.exist')
      .given({
        email: 'bob@gmail.com'
      })
      .login()
      .visit('/')
      .contains('Log out')
      .logout();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the [Cypress Real World App](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app), a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows in addition to a [Auth0 Authentication Testing Strategies Guide](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/auth0-authentication) which details the changes in to an Auth0 application and the [Cypress Real World App](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app).

Comment: The cypress real world app is really good and it's a great resource for Auth0 with Cypress  What I didn't understand though is the use of if (window.cypress) throughout the code in order to swap out the use of the id_token with the actual calls to the Auth0 React hook calls for getTokenSilently.   The other answer above has provided a way to mimic the exact which gets stored in the local storage and this seems to work for me.  Basically, I'm trying to understand if or why I need to adapt my code with  if (window.cypress)  to make it work?